# how to put textview on top of a datepicker

Tags: android, datepicker, textview, scrollview, android-linearlayout

im trying to build a form, with a textview and a datepicker,something like:
|Date:         |
|datePickerHere|
the problem is i think i have the "same" code as the developer guide but it isnt working. it always ends up like:
|Date: datePickerHere|

Heres the code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:text="@string/data_label"/>

        <DatePicker
            android:id="@+id/data"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
 <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

to

```
 <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
```

Linear Layouts will default to horizontal orientation if you don't specify the "android:orientation" tag. You must specify it as vertical to achieve what you want